# How to hide one of new HTML5 elements in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I have something like:

```
<div id="body-no-aside">

  <div id="content">
    Some contents
  </div>

  <aside id="aside">
    Something aside
  </aside>

</div>
```

I'm including html5shiv.js in header of my page.

Now, this CSS doesn't seem to work for IE8 (the #aside is still visible):

```
#body-no-aside #aside {
  display: none;
}
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: what is the id in the dom of the aside element when the shiv is loaded?

Comment: It's #aside all the time.

Comment: in developer tools on IE8 you can see that the google shiv loaded and that the id of the aside element is #aside for sure?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just calling

```
#aside{display:none;}
```

There is no good reason to select beyond the id, if you are using it. It is the highest of all the selectors. I don't know if that will solve your problem, but I'm sure ie8 with js shiv should be able to select just an id of an aside. The css3 descentant combinator (#body-no-aside #aside) might be the issue.